# How can I find out the type by accessing the column of the index of the models.all() result?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-orm

How can I find out the type by accessing the column of the index of the models.all() result??

My code is like this:

```
def qtj(result_model):
    for index in result_model:
        print('index : ', index)
        for column in index:
            print(f'column : {column} type:{type(column)}')
```

but this at index :
index :  {'board_seq': Decimal('15'), 'board_title': '제목', 'board_content': '내용', 'board_writer': '무명', 'board_password': '1234', 'create_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 27, 18, 6, 8, 586137)}

and in the column :
column : board_seq type:<class 'str'>

What I want to do is find the datetime.datetime, not the str.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the type of the corresponding value with:

```
def qtj(result_model):
    for index in result_model:
        print('index : ', index)
        for column, value in index.items():
            print(f'column : {column} type:{type(value)}')
```

Comment: index[column] = value.strftime("%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S")

and finally 

return result_model

I solved this thank you